# How to make a security group inactive in openerp?

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

I dont want the functionality of a security group in openerp. For example I want to remove the group "Properties on Lines" and its functionality. I know we can uncheck it from users/access rights or from the settings/ configuration. I dont want to list it anywhere in openerp. Is it possible and how?

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is possible. just delete the group, but beware the side effects, because it could have been used in some views and when it is deleted, the view wouldn't find it anymore and you will maybe get some errors.

Comment: Deleting is not an option as the group is specified in so many view. We cannot delete the group.

Comment: hm sorry, then i have no idea how to do that. :(